# Change SQL mode or edit query?

Tags: php, mysql

Since the latest update i get this error message:

> Failed to run query: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'table...' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

I have read about this issue and the threads i can found is to remove the mode "only_full_group_by"

Now, is this the best practice, or should i change my code?

How could my query look if i like to use the mySQL defaults?

**QUERY**

```
$query = "SELECT es.datum, es.objekt_element, es.anteckn, es.objekt_nr
      FROM element_skanning es
      INNER JOIN 
               (
                SELECT objekt_element, anteckn, MIN(datum) AS min_datum
                FROM element_skanning
                WHERE datum LIKE '$this_year_month'
                GROUP BY objekt_element
                HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
               )
      dup ON es.objekt_element = dup.objekt_element
      ORDER BY dup.min_datum, es.objekt_element, es.datum;
";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix your query by simply removing `anteckn` from the `SELECT` list of the inner query. That value is not used so it won't affect your results:

```
$query = "SELECT es.datum, es.objekt_element, es.anteckn, es.objekt_nr
      FROM element_skanning es
      INNER JOIN 
               (
                SELECT objekt_element, MIN(datum) AS min_datum
                FROM element_skanning
                WHERE datum LIKE '$this_year_month'
                GROUP BY objekt_element
                HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
               )
      dup ON es.objekt_element = dup.objekt_element
      ORDER BY dup.min_datum, es.objekt_element, es.datum;
";
```

Note that you will also want to include

```
es.datum = dup.min_datum
```

in your `JOIN` condition if (as it appears) you only want to get rows from `element_skanning` which correspond to the minimum value of `datum`.

Comment: Thank you. Should the es.datum = ... be in the WHERE clause? after $this_year_month ?

Comment: @BjörnC it should be in the `JOIN` condition i.e. change `dup ON es.objekt_element = dup.objekt_element` to `dup ON es.objekt_element = dup.objekt_element AND es.datum = dup.min_datum`